# Django: Display choice value not showing

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I know similar questions have been asked already but I am stumped. I have a list of Months in models.py:

```
MONTH_CHOICES = [
    (1, 'January'),
    (2, 'February'),
    (3, 'March'),
    .....etc.......
]

month = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False, blank=False)
```

In forms.py:

```
month = ChoiceField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES, required=True)
```

Then I have  a table where I want to display (winners.html) the month Value, (January, February, etc.) not (1,2,3......) and I have this:

```
{% for w in winners %}
    {{ w.get_month_display }}
```

Now instead of display the number (1,2,3......,) it just displays nothing at all. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told the model field to use the choices - so get_month_display won't even be defined.

Also, I don't understand why you have defined the field to be a char field of length 120: it should be an integer field, as that is what your values are.

```
month = models.IntegerField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES, null=False, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `choices` in form field but trying get it from model field. And why don't you use modelforms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/